# HTML Date min get by another date

Tags: php, html, date, max, min

I need some help: i wanna get the min parameter for the second date field from the value insert in the first date field:

```html
Check-In:
<input type="date" name="checkin" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" required>
Check-Out:
<input type="date" name="checkout" min="HERE I WANT TO GET DATE INSERT IN THE CHECK-IN FIELD" required>
```

Thanks to all and sorry if I'm a little bit noob, is my first time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can do it without JavaScript. This solution may help:

```
Check-In:
<input type="date" name="checkin" id="set" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" required onchange="setDate();">
Check-Out:
<input type="date" name="checkout" id="set1" required>
<script>
function setDate() {
    document.getElementById('set1').min = document.getElementById('set').value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this you would probably need to use ajax or Javascript

Here is some more details:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-pass-an-HTML-form-one-input-value-into-another-input-value-on-the-same-page